# I want to know what I can do with class based components that I cannot do with function based

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, router, react-component

I have started learning reactjs and I am loving it my query is, is there anything I can do with class-based components that I can't with function based?
I know the concept of classes in JS and I am pretty comfortable using classes but in react I felt that function-based components are much easier to learn.

Comment: If you're starting in react and want to understand how it works and how all things are connected I'll suggest you to start out with a class-based component they'll give you a much better understanding of how react works once you're comfortable with it you can switch to function based approach efficiently. In the case of usability, you can do any type of operation with both approaches it's a solely individual choice to use which type of component in-app.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, only class components can become error boundaries, the rest both function and class components can do the same.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will see what this is.

Answer (score 0):

Class components are also often used as singletons